# Proving deficient form of Tutte's theorem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm trying to prove the deficient version of Tutte's theorem. This is

> A graph G has a matching covering all vertices with the exception of at most k vertices if and only if for any subset S of V(G) it holds that the number of odd components of G-S is at most |S|+k

I've been looking at the proof for the standard Tutte's theorem and also comparing to the proof of Hall's theorem but I don't really know where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated